# Unable to add photo albums on my volunteer organization Facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I am a volunteer for a local business and my job is to photograph events and upload them as albums to their Facebook page.

They say they will and have added me as an administrator to their page. Why am I still having trouble seeing the "Create an album" tab when I go to their page and try to add the photos of an event?

Each time I try this I have to login which I do using my personal Facebook username and password.

Is there another aspect to this that I need to know? As far as my own Facebook page and business page that is something I do not want connected with this job.

Answer (score 2):

If the page option is not available in the "Use Facebook Page as" list (from the Account menu), then you are not an admin.

If you do see the option try switching and using Facebook as a page. If this does not work you may want to file an appropriate support request via [Facebook Help : Pages for Business](http://www.facebook.com/help/?page=175).

[image: Use Facebook Page As]